# ASP.NET Button OnClientClick

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have question and any help will be greatly appreciated.  I hope I am explaining this clearly, but if i'm not just let me know, i will be on for a while.  This is written in C# and I have a button that calls a javascript function called "JavaScript()" in the "OnClientClick" part and in the "OnClick" part I have an "if statement" where the first part resembles the OnClientClick function and the second part represents different code that is not related to the OnClientClick.

DefaultPage.aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
 OnClick="Button1_OnClick" 
 OnClientClick="JavaScript()"  />
```

DefaultPage.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
  String a = getValueofA();

  If (a == "1")
  {
            //OnClientClick code goes here
  }
  else If (a == "2")
  {
     //No OnClientClick code goes here
  }
 }
```

This javascript function comes from a different Web Control that I am loading on this "DefaultPage".  This worked perfect for me until I added the "if statement" in Button1_OnClick.  Originally I just had the first part of the "if statement", now I need to add the second part of it.  How can I accomplish this.  I tried button1.OnClientClick, but it only works in Page_Load.  I need to first determine the value of "a" then proceed.  Sorry if i'm not clear but i can answer any questions.  Thanks so much.  My goal is to remove the "OnClientClick=JavaScript" from my asp.net button and just call that function inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error are you getting?  If is not capitalized in C#.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h(v=vs.100).aspx

EDIT:

Based on the comments, I think you are better off going client side entirely.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function NewFunction(){
    var a = getValueOfA();
    if (a === "1")
    {
        JavaScript();
    }
    else if ( a==="2" )
    {
        //other code
    }
}
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
 OnClientClick="NewFunction()"  />
```

Comment: The error i'm getting is the the function "JavaScript()" is 'null or not defined'.  This happens when it is going into the second part of my "if statement" because the variables in the "JavaScript()" function are not related to the second part of the "if statement", they are only related to the first part. Thanks.

Comment: So, that means that your code executes correctly when a == "1"?

Comment: Yes, when I have the "OnClientClick=JavaScript()" in the asp button

Comment: See answer for new suggestion (Code in comments doesn't work).  Essentially, you can just wrap the existing javascript function client side.  No need to make the server do more than necessary.  Use this post if you still need to get to the server side... http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/

Comment: Sorry if I'm confusing, but the JavaScript() function is coming from a Web Control that I am loading on the DefaultPge at Page_Load.

Comment: Right, so you need to call that function from the client side.  Even though you are loading it dynamically in your code behind, it's client-side functions are still client-side only.  So you can call them client-side, by wrapping it in a different function (which is ok because it is in the global namespace) or you can go with the other answer of registering a startup script, but if you register the startup script, it will not fire until after your postback.

Comment: What does "it will not fire until after your postback" mean?  I'm sorry, but I'm just alittle confused.  Thanks again, i really appreciate your help.

Comment: It will not execute until after your server-side code executes and your page reloads.

Comment: I think that's my problem.  I need the function to execute before my server-side code gets executed.

Comment: Then you need to wrap it in javascript and if statement client-side.  Don't forget to mark as answer if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your questions, it seems like you want to execute javascript code from the code behind. How about using ScriptManager in the code behind and execute javascript from there? like below

```
    // write your onclientclick code here
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "JAVA_SCRIPT", "your javascript() function code here", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When I use the ScriptManager I can add it in the code behind where the button click is called?  I only need to call the JavaScript function for one part of my if statment.  Thanks again!